# What makes the execution order of threads unpredictable?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system

What makes the execution order of threads unpredictable? Does the scheduler at some point use random numbers or check system resources or see which thread has waited long enough or ...?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The scheduler is, usually, the OS's scheduler. It is influenced by many factors, including what other processes on the machine are doing, what the hardware is doing (interrupts), etc. Depending on the OS, I suppose there may sometimes be random numbers involved, but I suspect generally not. It's more just the unpredictable way that multiple variable time intervals can overlap.

Answer (score 4):

Using random numbers in the scheduler would introduce unnecessary overhead into a critical section of the OS, so it's very unlikely that is the cause, at least in any mainstream OS.

A thread usually runs until it makes an OS call that would block, or until an interrupt occurs, or until its time slice expires (which ultimately is just a timer interrupt). Even if you could carefully construct things so that two threads would always block in a deterministic order, you have no control over precisely when the latter two effects will occur. The order the threads in your application are executed in will eventually be influenced by events outside your application.

Answer (score 1):

Other questions make good points with technical details, but:

To be precise, thread scheduling in Java is fairly efficiently controlled by **locks**, **wait/notify/notifyAll**, **sleep** methods and other concurrency controls.
Only at those times during application execution, **when these are not present**, the execution order of different threads **is left undefined**.

Main reason is probably for the sake of ease of portability of Java in different hardware/OS systems. It is also only logical, that if you as a developer do not define order in which different threads in your app should be executed using above mentioned concurrency controls, you do not care about it and it just does not matter then and arbitrary way may be chosen by the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon the JVM, JVM might transfer the thread as it is to OS and OS scheduler will schedule the thread, or JVM may decide to schedule the thread itself, so the very first difference (unpredictable behavior on 2 different machine for same situation) comes here, whether thread is being scheduled by JVM or OS, u cant be really sure.....
Moreover there are number of factors, priority of thread is one factor (we can set the priority), resource is another factor....Its less likely that random numbers are involved.

Comment: All current mainstream JVMs leave scheduling entirely to the OS. Some older JVMs used green threads, but in that case *all* thread scheduling was managed by the JVM.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt i guess SCJP book for java 6 needs to include this explanation, they dnt mention difference abt old and new JVM's in the book! anyways thanks for updating

Answer (score 0):

Modern operating systems use what's known as [Preemtive multitasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_multitasking#Preemptive_multitasking.2Ftime-sharing). It guarantees each process on the system a slice of CPU time, with various rules for when to interrupt each one and let the next have a turn. This is why you don't need one CPU per process on your machine :)

It's not random, but it is generally unpredictable.