# Use threading in a loop, how to finish for loop before reaching to end of the main program?

Tags: java, multithreading

My expected output is

```
Count : 1
Count : 2
Count : 3
Count : 4
Count : 5
```

I have tried synchronized and Lock but neither of them works. I reach to

> Ending Main

sooner than I finish the loop completely. Current output is:

```
Starting Main
Count : 1
Count : 2
Count : 3
Count : 4
Ending Main
Count : 5
```

Any Idea why  Count : 5 is after Ending Main? Here is my code:

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Starting Main" ) ;
        for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++ ) {
            Thread numberThread = new Thread(new NumberTask(i)) ;
            numberThread.start() ;
        }
        System.out.println( "Ending Main" ) ; 
    }
}

class NumberTask implements Runnable {
    private Lock bankLock = new ReentrantLock();
    int count ;
    public NumberTask( int count ) {
        this.count = count ;
    }

    synchronized public void run() {
        bankLock.lock();
        try {
            System.out.println( "Count : " + count ) ;
        } finally {
            bankLock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you need the output to be a specific way?  Why use threads at all then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use join() to wait for other thread to finish. Your code need to be updated as follows:

```
public static void main( String [] args ) {

    System.out.println( "Starting Main" ) ;
        Thread numberThread;
        for ( int i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++ ) {
            numberThread = new Thread(new NumberTask(i)) ;
            numberThread.start() ;
        }
        numberThread.join();
        System.out.println( "Ending Main" ) ; 
    }
```

Comment: it does not work because i think numberThread.join(); must be inside the loop. anyway still I got the idea!

Comment: With the join _inside_ the loop there is no point to fork any of the threads @Bernard.  You might as well just call `new NumberTask(i).run();` from the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

> Any Idea why "Count : 5" is after "Ending Main"?

When a thread is started, there is no guarantee that it starts running immediately.  It is normal for the thread that forked the new thread to continue to run as the new thread initializes.  So, after the main thread starts the 5th thread, it continues to run and beats the thread to the `System.out.println("Ending Main");` statement.

It is important to realize that the whole point of threads is that they run in an asynchronous manner.  Because the threads can be scheduled on separate CPUs/cores running concurrently, it is often very hard to predict the order of operations in a thread program.  For example. it is also possible that you might see "Count 2" printed *before* "Count 1" just because of [thread race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Computing).  I just ran it starting 500 threads and I saw:

```
Count : 128
Count : 130
Count : 129
Count : 131
```

Also, because your `bankLock` is local to your `NumberTask` class, it will not lock *between* threads.  You could make the lock static to `NumberTask` to have there be one lock *per-class* or you could instantiate the lock in main and pass it into the `NumberTask` constructor.  You really don't need the lock here since the `System.out` is a `PrintStram` which is a `synchronized` object.  The same goes for the `synchronized` `run()` method.  Since you will be synchronizing on the `NumberTask` instance, it doesn't do anything because no other thread will be synchronizing on the same object.

Comment: I defined  'bankLock' as a static but still i'm not getting constant output. The reason I'm using lock is because I wanted my loop starts from one to 5 in order. the problem has been solved by using 'join()'. but why the Lock does not work I have no idea.

Comment: You can never be guaranteed that it will go from 1 to 5 @Bernard unless you use a lot of locking or use a single thread.  Again, as my answer states, the whole point of threading is asynchronous and concurrent running.

Answer (score 0):

Execution of threads is not predictable, so you get this behavior. Use [join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) method to make one thread's execution to the end of another thread's execution.

Kindly read [Java thread unpredictable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915337/java-thread-unpredictable)