# Order a Runtime exec and a ProcessBuilder.start?

Tags: java, process, exec, runtime.exec

I've been confronted to a weird problem while running and killing processes through java.

Basically, I have a method which kills one process using taskkill :

```
private static void kill() {
    try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F /IM app.exe");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I call this method to be sure all the processes are killed before I start a new one :

```
    kill();
    ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);

    try {
        Process p = procBuilder.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is the process started seems to be killed by the taskkil. Without the call to kill, it works perfectly fine; while with the kill, the process starts but the GUI doesn't appear.

Is this a problem of priority between the two calls ? (a runtime.exec would be of lower priority than a ProcessBuilder.start ?).

I've solved that using a waitFor on the return of the Runtime exec but I'm curious about why this problem appeared.

Comment: *"I call this method to be sure all the processes are killed"*  Are you trying to create a single instance application?  Whatever it is you are trying to achieve, I expect this is the wrong way to go about it.  This strategy is like 'shoot everything that moves'.

Comment: The strategy is more like 'shoot everything'... whether it's moving or not...More seriously, what are the alternatives considering i'm not guaranted i start all those processes and there may be some dead one amongst them ?

Answer (score 2):

Basically the `Runtime.exec` starts a new process in the OS asynchronously, and there is no guarantee that it is finished before your new process is started. Theoretically you sould wait for the `taskkill` to return with a `SUCCESS` result and start your new job only after that. According to its documentation `taskkill` will tell you with 0 return code if it has successfully killed its suspect.

Comment: but i thought ProcessBuilder was doing the same thing

Comment: @LB. it does.  Whether you use `Runtime.exec` or `ProcessBuilder` the same rules apply - you get a `Process` object back and you need to read anything from `p.getInputStream()` and `p.getErrorStream()` and then `waitFor` the process to complete.

Comment: @Ian. gotcha, so there's no guarantee whatsoever, it's more like flipping a coin. The fact that killing was executed after the starting was not representative and It could be the other way around, seamlessly

Comment: @LB see my answer for an argument on the delay.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not priority related, since both of them will have the default priority. A possible issue is that `Runtime.exec` using a `String` will have to parse the input and then execute the command, while `ProcessBuild` will execute the given command without the needed parsing logic. Because of this you can see a small delay and you need the `waitFor` to work as intended. You can eliminate this delay by using the `String[]` version of the `Runtime.exec`.
Also note that the threads are scheduled by the system scheduler and the execution order is unpredictable, see [Java thread unpredictable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7915346/1613867).

Comment: No, it won't.  `Runtime.exec(String)` simply splits the string at whitespace using a `StringTokenizer` and passes the resulting array to `exec(String[])`.  If you want to use `cmd` you need to say so explicitly: `exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", commandString})`

Comment: @Ian that is the parsing that I was talking about. Will update the answer, I'm on mobile right now and it's a pain to update.